# VBA to snap image to cell border

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that inserts tick marks that we use in audits onto pages when they are being reviewed.
It worked perfectly for a while, but recently the pictures that are inserted tend to paste in the incorrect spot and we have to manually drag it around.

```
Global picname As String
____________________________
Sub TB1_()
'sets the name of the tick to be inserted
    picname = "b1.png"
    Call insertticks
End Sub
____________________________
Sub insertticks()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim imagePath As String
    Dim imgLeft As Single
    Dim imgTop As Single
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

'Disable shared workbooks - this conflicts with our software
    If ActiveWorkbook.MultiUserEditing Then
    ActiveWorkbook.ExclusiveAccess
    End If

'Enable all shapes because sometimes it won't paste
    ActiveWorkbook.DisplayDrawingObjects = xlDisplayShapes
    
'Set the filename 
imagePath = "C:\Users\" & Environ("UserName") & "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLStart\Ticks\" & picname

'set left and top parameters 
    imgLeft = ActiveCell.Left
    imgTop = ActiveCell.Top

'Add picture
    ws.Shapes.AddPicture _
    Filename:=imagePath, _
    LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
    SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=imgLeft, _
    Top:=imgTop, _
    Width:=11.85, _
    Height:=11.85

'Reactivate automatic calculation of sheet in case of debug error that disables it
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

'move to next cell
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
End Sub
```

This code used to work 100% of the time but for about a month now it tends to insert the picture one cell up from the active cell, or in the middle of the cell above and the active cell. In some instances it has pasted more than 3 cells away!

Comment: How is the code being executed? When the code doesn't work as expected have you checked that ActiveCell is what you expect it to be?

Comment: It executes on a button click from the ribbon. the active cell should be whatever cell is highlighted at the time of the button press

Answer (score 0):

I use the following.

Set opic as your file
Amend the row and column heights where needed.
x variable needs to be changed to the row number.
"G" needs to be changed to the column letter

```
Dim opic As Shape

Set opic = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture("c:\test.jpg", False, True, 1, 1, -1, -1)
    With opic
        .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
        .width = 75 * 1.5 - 2
        .Height = 100 * 1.5 - 2
        ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 1).EntireRow.RowHeight = 100 * 1.5
        ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 7).EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 75
        .Left = ActiveSheet.Cells(x, "G").Left + 1
        .Top = ActiveSheet.Cells(x, "G").Top + 1
        .Placement = 1
    End With
Set opic = Nothing
```

EDIT just knocked it up into a function for you

```
Function add_image(path As String, row As Integer, col As String):
    ' path = image file path
    'row = row number
    ' col = column letter i.e "A"
    ' change the width and height values to suit
    Dim opic As Shape
    Set opic = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(path, False, True, 1, 1, -1, -1)
        With opic
            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
            .width = 75 * 1.5 - 2
            .Height = 100 * 1.5 - 2
            ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 1).EntireRow.RowHeight = 100 * 1.5
            ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 7).EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 75
            .Left = ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col).Left + 1
            .Top = ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col).Top + 1
            .Placement = 1
        End With
    Set opic = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Ok I've tweaked it

Comment: Why should he modify the picture dimensions, the row and column dimensions, since his (claimed) problem is not well positioning on the cell Left/Top?

Comment: Use it as you like, remove or delete which ever lines are irrelevant.

Comment: I am not the OP... I only wanted to understand why you proposed such a code like a solution to his problem. Theoretically, his code should run correctly. We should focus on something unusual which may happen there...

Comment: Used bits and pieces from this, but it still sets it in the middle of 2 cells.

Comment: Ok think i figured it out. If I open excel and run it, it works perfectly. If I open the excel file through my company software, it glitches out. something seems to be causing trouble with the add-in.

Comment: @FaneDuru You could ponder all day as to how my brain works, but I saw a problem that struck a chord with me and I offered some help. I'm not here for glory, I'm here to better my own ability. I agree with your comments, I didn't really answer his question. But I offered my own take on in.  Right or wrong, its a method that might help the OP get to the bottom of their issue by seeing another route. Who knows hey?